# Running uWSGI In emperor mode but slows down computer

Tags: python, uwsgi

I've been trying to run my applications with emperor mode and got it working but the problem is the moment i run emperor mode my computer slows down like crazy and i can't do anything. My configuration files code for both applications are similar.

```
[uwsgi]
module = Restful
chdir = path

processes = 2

http-socket = :5001
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

[uwsgi]
module = Flaskapp
chdir = /home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/
wsgi-file = Work/wsgi.py
processes = 2

http-socket = :5000
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

My code i run is

```
uwsgi --emperor vassals --uid http --gid http --master
```

It works and i see that both my apps are running at the same time but a few seconds later my laptop slows down. Anything I'm doing wrong? it was working the first time i tried then after that it slowed down. I also made an emperor.ini file in my vassals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait you have an emperor.ini file? If it has configuration similar to what you have put in your uwsgi code, then it's probably running it twice and slowing down your computer?

Comment: oh... right that makes sense. It was working before but after I made the emperor.ini files it started slowing down hmm

Comment: Yes just delete the emperor.ini file or change your code as it's doing the same thing twice.

Comment: Which one should I do though?

Comment: You can do either. Delete the emperor.ini file and run the code for emperor and it should work with no slowing down.

Comment: No problem. I'm working on the same thing, your code looks similar to a friend of mines..hmm